# call wget() from rexx - how to get RC?

Tags: rexx

I need to call "wget" or "curl" from rexx.

And I need to get return code,
as I can do it I call the routine from Bash and use "$?".

How is it done ?

I am using Guindous and

```
C:\>rexx -v
Open Object Rexx Version 4.1.3
Build date: Jul  4 2013
Addressing Mode: 64
```

Is it "RC" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `RC` special variable is where you get a process' exit status from, assuming you've run it as a host command (*e.g.* via `ADDRESS`, either explicitly or implicitly).  If you really are calling a function via `CALL`, the function's return value is in `RESULT`.